# Rails shows incorrect time spent in a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I do-
`$ time curl 'http://localhost:3000'`
I get this:  `0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.270 total`
Gem 'rack-mini-profiler' also show time taken almost same as curl.

But in the rails log, I see-
`Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 72.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)`

Why there is time difference of about 1 second?

Curl and rails server both are running on my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

"time curl" is timing how long the curl client takes to fetch Rails content, ie it's the client time.

The Rails log is showing you the server time.

Comment: I looked into it, gem 'rack-mini-profiler' also show time taken almost same as curl.

Comment: Not sure why. It's possible other Rack middleware is being inserted after the logging output happens, ie, a 3rd party gem. Mini-profiler might help diagnose it.

Comment: It seems delay happen at the start of the web request, At the start of request it shows `Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-04 19:07:40 +0530` then I see about one second of delay, after this delay it shows further log output. How can I diagnose what is causing this delay?

Comment: Also one weird thing I noticed, when I restart the rails server, For first request I don't see this delay, but any other request I make after first request, I can see this one second delay.

Comment: That's not good. I would add more profiling and try to remove 3rd party gems to see if they are affecting it. You can also try hooking into certain parts of the request lifecycle and logging the time. You might also consider switching Rack server, e.g. to Unicorn to see if it affects this. Just some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify that but if you are running development mode, there is classes reloading and assets compilation, which heavily impacts response time. But it does not affect production.

Here is what I got in my rails 4.2 application (first curl, than corresponding excerpts from log):

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000'  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.817 total
curl 'http://localhost:3000'  0.01s user 0.00s system 2% cpu 0.366 total


Completed 200 OK in 1254ms (Views: 1206.2ms | ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2014:19:48:52 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 1.6863

Completed 200 OK in 279ms (Views: 278.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2014:19:49:41 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.2895
```

While in production:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000'  0.01s user 0.00s system 3% cpu 0.329 total
curl 'http://localhost:3000'  0.00s user 0.01s system 11% cpu 0.090 total

I, [2014-10-04T19:54:02.739988 #27830]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 123.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)
I, [2014-10-04T19:54:17.521175 #27830]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 40.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So differences persist there, but it's probably due to time for send request from curl to server and then to receive the response. I still think that bigger differences in development are caused by reloading and compiling.

Comment: Doesn't time spent in request shown by rails log include  asset compilation, and classes reloading?

Comment: That's just my guess, but it would not make sens to count class reloading to request time. I've edited my answer with more insight.